# Write a source code in java and compile it to various executables in other languages? Multi compilation?

Tags: java, python, c++, cross-compiling

Is it possible to write source code in one language ( e.g. python/java/c++) and make a compiler produce various binaries/ executables to run in other languages - **simultaneously**?

Do people do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "run in other languages".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here
[Translating Java bytecode into other representations and programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638491/translating-java-bytecode-into-other-representations-and-programming-languages)

Java Source compiles into bytecode then you can reverse engineer into other languages as mentioned there.

The code it produces will definitely need some idiomatic changes.

Similarly in the .net world CLR managed code and possibly be reverse engineered.

Again the dompilation from managed common code is possible however for unmanaged code it is not very readable.

See more info about this here:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-are-machine-code-decompilers-less-capable-than-for-example-those-for-the-clr

Comment: As far as i know there is no compiler for multi languages/polygot however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688936/finding-a-multilanguage-compiler-or-optimizer-c-c-java , however you can use tools to then generate source to compile on the intended language compiler.